# Convert list to sequence

Tags: list-manipulation

I was just thinking how [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) was created so , I came up with this,

```
Flatten[Outer[List, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}], 2] == Tuples[{a, b}, 3]
```

> True

Now, I want to convert it to a function,

```
fun[x_List] := Block[{}, Flatten[Outer[List, x], Length[x] - 1]]
```

But the problem is the I need to put this `List` as a sequence but I am not finding a work around.

Comment: Just a wild guess: `{a, b, c} /. List -> Sequence` does something like this work?

Comment: I generally don't face it, in fact I have answered 2-3 questions that used it, but I don't know what the problem is. It is converting all sublists to sequences.

Comment: @bobthechemist it certainly does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) and [`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConstantArray.html) (or `Table`):

```
fun[x_List, n_Integer] := Flatten[Outer[List, ##] & @@ ConstantArray[x, n], 2]

fun[{a, b}, 3] == Tuples[{a, b}, 3]
(* True *)
```

Comment: I tried using slotsequence,looks like I wasn't getting the syntax right. Thanks :)

Comment: Good example of SlotSequence, which I never seem to think of.

Comment: I believe that `Flatten` argument `2` should be `n-1` ..

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach with `Table`.

```
fun[x_List, n_Integer] := Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ Table[x, {n}]], n-1]
```

examples

```
fun[{a, b}, 3]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, b, a}, {a, b, b}, {b, a, a}, {b, a, b}, {b,
>      b, a}, {b, b, b}}

---

```
fun[{a, b}, 4]
```

> {{a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, b}, {a, a, b, a}, {a, a, b, b}, {a, b, a, 
>     a}, {a, b, a, b}, {a, b, b, a}, {a, b, b, b}, {b, a, a, a}, {b, a, 
>     a, b}, {b, a, b, a}, {b, a, b, b}, {b, b, a, a}, {b, b, a, b}, {b, 
>     b, b, a}, {b, b, b, b}}

Comment: Apply seems a good option to. But using `{{a,b},{c,d}}/.List->Sequence` should be applied only once as a replace once rule, but it goes down the list generating `Sequence[a, b, c, d]`

Comment: Hmmm. I wasn't aware of that.  I'll try to fix it.